# Login control won't login

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I've been using VS 2013 and created an Asp.Net web forms application using the template with Bootstrap. I have a login control that does all of the default behaviour using AspNet tables within SQL. When I run within the IDE I have no problems in any browser logging into the site (IE, Chrome) I was manly using IE when running.

However, I have deployed the site to my local server for testing and it stops working in IE. What happens is it goes through the validation of the user name/password fine, gets to the redirect but the user is never logged in.

If I browse to the server using chrome on my pc it will work fine if I do the same within IE it won't work 95% of the time but I have managed to login occasionally. I have asked other colleague's to try, Chrome doesn't work for most of them or IE. I have also tried on my ipad chrome will work but safari won't!

So in file startup.auth.vb

Partial Public Class Startup

```
' For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301883
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
    'Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)

    ' Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
            .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
        .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})

    ' Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)

    ' Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))

    ' Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    ' Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    ' This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie)

  End Sub
End Class
```

Then on my login button

```
Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsValid Then
        ' Validate the user password
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

        ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
        ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
        Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)

        Select Case result
            Case SignInStatus.Success
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                Exit Select
            Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout")
                Exit Select
            Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                                RememberMe.Checked),
                                  True)
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt"
                ErrorMessage.Visible = True
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Show you client side code.. button won't be getting *Click* event probably.

Comment: It's not a button click issue (might be wrong!) because when i click the login button the page redirect happens which means it's executed the 'click' as that's the last action performed when it gets the result from Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(....) then Select Case result   Case SignInStatus.Success redirect... thanks in advance

Comment: I'm thinking it must be something with the authentication cookie? because to redirect back to a page it thinks it's has had a successful signin but then loading any other pages it's not finding the authentication cookie?? but that's me guessing

Comment: in that case show us how you are creating the cookie....

Comment: Thanks for the response Mych, i'm just guessing about the cookie the reality is i don't have a clue whats going wrong i'm just trying to follow through what seems to be happening i'm not doing anything more really than what the web application template sets up as default will post some code bits thanks

Comment: so in startup.auth.vb -   ' Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
                .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(

Comment: validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
            .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})

Comment: then on my login button - Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

            Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)

            Select Case result
                Case SignInStatus.Success                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                    Exit Select

Comment: is there any more code Chris? as the select case seems incomplete.

Comment: Edit your question and put that code in there so it is readable.

Comment: Hi zaf yes there's a bit more code i ran out of words in the comment section but thanks epascarello i hadn't even thought about editing main post and putting it there!!! but i have updated now thanks in advance